# Problems mounting Nexus 7

Tags: mtp

[image]

I am having problems connecting my Nexus 7 to my Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: ? Please add more information, and make sure that `libmtp` is installed.

Comment: libmtp is not installed. And using these commands is  not helping. ./configure
make
sudo make install for libmtp 1.1.3 downloaded from sourceforge

Comment: This error shows up when run mtp-detect from the terminal.


libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s) mtp-detect: symbol lookup error: mtp-detect: undefined symbol: LIBMTP_Detect_Raw_Devices

Comment: Don't compile it, search for it using `sudo apt-cache search libmtp` and install using `apt-get`. @barry 's answer has a bit on it.

Comment: I did, but same error. I also tried what barry posted. It just doesn't work. Even when the Nexus 7 is unlocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally re installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. MTP devices such as Nexus 7, Sony Cybershot Camera and other android devices work just fine. 
I found the problem. When I was unable to mount my Windows Phone, I installed a few mtp tools and libmtp. After that I was unable to mount my android devices. 
Even uninstalling these mtp tools and libmtp didn't help so I re installed the O.S.

Conclusion : No need of extra libraries for mtp enabled devices. Ubuntu is fine with them.
             Also, forget about trying to mount Windows phone 7.8 or 7.5 on Ubuntu. It is
             not possible right now.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your specific problem, but when I was doing this recently the instructions which finally got a Nexus 7 mounted on my machine with Ubuntu 12.04 were here at Jeshurun's Blog (see below):

http://blog.jeshurun.ca/technology/connecting-the-google-nexus-7-to-ubuntu-mint-over-usb

I had tried one or two other how-tos which had failed.

1. Open a terminal
2. Create a udev rules file for the Nexus 7 with it’s device id (18d1)

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
   ```
3. Paste the following contents into the file, save and exit:

   ```
   # Nexus 7
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
   ```

   You can find a list of vendor ids for various Android OEMs here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds
4. Make the file executable (gotta love the security on Linux)

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules
   ```
5. Install the mtp libraries from the repos

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9 mtpfs mtp-tools
   ```
6. Create a mount point for the Nexus 7 and make it accessible to all users

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/nexus7
   sudo chmod 755 /media/nexus7
   ```
7. Finally plug your Nexus 7 into an empty USB slot on your comptuer and run the following command on the terminal:

   ```
   sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/nexus7
   ```
8. In a few seconds, the tablet should appear mounted as an external drive on your file browser.
9. Note that these steps are applicable to all Debian based systems including Ubuntu and Linux Mint
10. When you are done moving files, unmount the mounted folder before unplugging the device.

    ```
    sudo umount /media/nexus7
    ```

Comment: Very good, but you could embed those instructions into your answer... ;-)

Comment: How should I format it?

Comment: As you like - it just is useful, as links, particularly blog links, won't always exist in the future. Use the `` code tags for the commands, and bullets points or something for the steps.  More [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I even tried reinstalling dbus. It just doesn't work.